# Red/green colourings of a $n\times m$ rectangle with an odd number of green cells in any $2\times 2$ grid.

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways are there to color a $n$ by $m$ rectangle, such that each cell in the rectangle is either red or green and so that every $2$ by $2$ rectangle within it has an odd number of green cells?

So for an $2$ by $2$ rectangle, there are $8$ ways. How do I generalize?

Comment: How do you get 8? or how do you generalize from there?

Comment: @DougM generalize it

Comment: @DougM Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many ways are there to color the 2x3 rectangle?
there are 2, 2x2 grids.  Of which they share a pair of blocks.
pick a 2x2 grid, there are 8 ways to color it.  The 2 open cells, if they boarder a solid red or a solid green then they must be (green, red) or (red,green) -- there are two ways to do that.  If the shared edge is two color, then they must be solid, and can be green or red.

2 x 3 = 16 ways.
2 x 4 = 32 ways. etc.
2 x n = $2^{n+1}$ ways
so now suppose we have a 3xn?
we color in the 2xn portion.  We choose any pair of colored squares in the uncolored row, might as well start at the right edge of the row.  There are 2 ways to color it.  But that is all the freedom you have.  Slide to the 1 to the right, and there is a 2x2 that has 3 cells already filled in.  For the rest of the row just follow the rules.

m x n = $2^{n+m-1}$